# Syntax Question for exec (executing two commands)

Tags: vimrc

In my .vimrc, I have the following exec command:

```
inoremap <C-f> <Esc>: silent exec '.!inkscape-figures create "'.getline('.').'" "'.b.vimtex.root.'/figures/"'<CR><CR>:w<CR>
```

where inkscape-figures create (figure) is a bash command. However, I want to include the following command

```
inkscape-figures watch
```

to be executed when I press CTRL+F in insert mode.

I dont understand the syntax of exec and I haven't found anything similar online.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you clarify what parts you don’t understand? Have you read `:help :execute` and `:help :map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that "exec" is used to execute external shell commands, but that's not the case.

The [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) command is simply used to run a Vimscript from a string, and this is used in this case to assemble a shell command-line from a string, to include arguments for the contents of the current line and also the path to the `figures/` directory.

Then this is being passed to a `:.!` command, which runs the external command on a shell, passing the current line through the standard input, and then replacing the current line with the output produced by the external command. (See [`:help :range!`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Arange%21), where `.` is being used as a range for the current line.)

> However, I want to include the `inkscape-figures watch` command to be executed when I press CTRL+F in insert mode.

You can similarly use that as a filter, or use the [`:r!`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#%3Ar%21) command to simply read the output of the external command, without any input, and pasting it below the current line.

For example:

```
:r!inkscape-figures watch
```

If that's what you want, you can map that to the Ctrl-F combination in insert mode using:

```
inoremap <C-f> <Esc>:r!inkscape-figures watch<CR>o
```

It seems you actually want to execute *both* commands with the Ctrl-F keypress. You can surely do that, either use the two commands in sequence with `<CR>` in between them, or execute both commands in a single shell separating them with `;` or perhaps `&&` (i.e. anything you can do on a shell.)

We'd need more details about what *exactly* you want to be able to give you a more detailed and complete answer, but hopefully this addresses your point about "exec" and gives you enough pointers to be able to come up with a useful mapping on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have exactly been looking for this!